# Regex for parsing one or two directories

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that would recognise both:

`website.com/jobs/value1`

`website.com/jobs/value1/value2`

At the moment I have `'jobs/[^/]+/[^/]+';`

But the first link isn't recognised but the second is.

Is there a way of writing this so it would recognise if there was one or two directories after `jobs` and not if there was a third?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention it the original questions, but I would also need it to recognise:-

`website.com/jobs`

as well as the above two links.

Comment: What about a tailing / ? like `website.com/jobs/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making the second directory optional:

```
jobs(/[^/]+){0,2}$
```

This should match the following things:

```
website.com/jobs
website.com/jobs/value1
website.com/jobs/value1/value2
```

But it would not match three paths after `/jobs`.

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Comment: Awesome, this works, but now `website.com/jobs/` doesn't work, can both be made optional?

Comment: @nsilva jobs(\/[^\/]+){0,2}\/?$

Comment: @nsilva I updated my answer per your new requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much @TimBiegeleisen - perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
jobs/([^/]+/?){0,2}$
```

`([^/]+/?)` matches a sequence of one or more none `/` chars, optinally followed by a `/`. `{0,2}` means zero, one or two times.

Comment: I think this would match `website.com/jobs/value1/value2/` ... see [here](https://regex101.com/r/XmR0bV/3).

Comment: Yeah. Wasn't this the problem here?